# Access to Singleton values from his method in ExtJS 5.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, singleton, extjs5

I created a `SingletonClass` in ExtJS 5.1 with values `numero` and `texto`, i can execute gets and sets but if i try to execute any method of that SingletonClass shows values as `undefined`.

```
//SingletonClass.js - Ampliación 8
Ext.define('js.SingletonClass', {
    singleton : true,
    config : {
        numero : 6,
        texto : "nulo"
    },
    elNumero : function () {
        alert("El número de la clase es: " + this.numero);
    },
    elTexto : function () {
        alert("El texto de la clase es: " + js.SingletonClass.getTexto());
    }
});
```

as you can see i tried with `this.numero` and another method with `js.SingletonClass.getTexto()` but not works

```
// APP.js - Instanciar clase singleton 

js.SingletonClass.setNumero(10);
alert(js.SingletonClass.getNumero()); // Show: '10'

js.SingletonClass.elNumero(); // Undefined value
js.SingletonClass.elTexto(); // Undefined value
```

How can i access from my SingletonClass to their own attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. As per the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-config), you need to call `initConfig` in your constructor. This applies to singletons too.
2. You are using setters/getters, so don't try accessing `this.numero`. Use `this.getNumero()` instead.

All together:

```js
Ext.define('js.SingletonClass', {
    singleton : true,
    config : {
        numero : 6,
        texto : "nulo"
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    },
    elNumero : function () {
        alert("El número de la clase es: " + this.getNumero());
    },
    elTexto : function () {
        alert("El texto de la clase es: " + js.SingletonClass.getTexto());
    }
});
js.SingletonClass.setNumero(10);
alert(js.SingletonClass.getNumero());
js.SingletonClass.elNumero();
js.SingletonClass.elTexto();
```

Comment: Thank you!
My problem was  the constructor.